Codegen graphql hooks and functions into separate files but in the same folder and without generating a base types?
I'm using graphql-codegen to generate apoollo mutations and queries into separate files (I noticed tree shaking does not work at all with a single generated graphql file).
This is where I'm at in my config, I can generate but the files have to be colocated which I don't want (to make updating all the imports easier):
import { CodegenConfig } from "@graphql-codegen/cli";

const config: CodegenConfig = {
  schema: {
    "http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql": {
      headers: {
      },
    },
  },
  documents: [
    "./**/*.graphql",
    "./**/*.ts",
    "./**/*.tsx",
    "!./node_modules/**",
    "!./generated/*.ts",
    "!./**/*.generated.*.ts",
  ],
  generates: {
    "generated/types.ts": {
      plugins: [
        {
          typescript: {
            noExport: true,
          },
        },
        {
          "typescript-operations": {
            noExport: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    "generated/": {
      preset: "near-operation-file",
      presetConfig: {
        extension: ".generated.tsx",
        baseTypesPath: "types.ts", // can we avoid having this?
      },
      plugins: ["typescript-operations", "typescript-react-apollo"],
    },
    "generated/graphql-types.d.ts": {
      plugins: [
        {
          typescript: {
            noExport: true,
          },
        },
        {
          "typescript-operations": {
            noExport: true,
          },
        },
      ],
      config: {
        enumsAsTypes: true,
      },
    },
    "generated/graphql-frags.ts": {
      plugins: [
        {
          "fragment-matcher": {
            apolloClientVersion: 3,
            module: "es2015",
            useExplicitTyping: false,
          },
        },
      ],
      config: {
        skipTypename: true,
        enumsAsTypes: true, // to ensure enums are not generated
      },
    },
    "generated/graphql-enums.ts": {
      plugins: ["typescript"],
      config: {
        onlyEnums: true,
      },
    },
    "generated/graphql-sdk.ts": {
      config: {
        rawRequest: true,
        enumsAsTypes: true, // to ensure enums are not generated
      },
      plugins: ["typescript-graphql-request"],
    },
  },
};

export default config;

I also don't want to do a baseTYpesPath in near-operation-file because  "generated/graphql-types.d.ts" does exactly what that does without needing to import a giant types file into each individual code gen'd file. In fact if I comment out the 'import * as types from 'types'' in the generated files and remove the Types.[type]  from each usage it compiles and runs fine which for me feels like a cleaner solution that won't bog down the typoescript transpiling or accidentally break tree shaking.
Any thoughts on how to accomplish the two above?
